# On deploy I am hitting the 10k file limit, is there a way I can I test if files are being excluded?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

I am hitting the 10k limit. I am trying to exclude files and folders from being uploaded and but It seems like they are not being excluded. I am testing by just trying to deploy a new version to app engine.

Is there a way to test the deploy without actually deploying to app engine?

(I am using java app engine standard (not maven))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One usual culprit here is using git, and accidentally uploading the contents `.git`. If you are using git, adding `.git` to the `skip_files:` section in your `app.yaml` (or as in exlusion an the `<resource-files>` section of your `appengine-web.xml`) should cure the problem.

Comment: I checked to see if .git is in the build and it is not so that's good. Do you know of a way to see what will be uploaded without actually uploading the files to the server.

Comment: The deployer keeps a logfile somewhere that shows what it's doing. That's how I figured out the .git problem when I had it a few years ago. Check the `gcloud` docs, if that's what you're using to deploy. There might be a helpful command-line option. I'm not near a system that has a deployment environment today.